# Ajax data parse

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I have a page with comments. By ajax, send a request to php page by. Php then scans the database... In general the standard logical operations. In any case, I meet php

```
echo '<script>show_info("my_text")</script>';
```

(show_info - js function which toggle info div and it displays my text).
And if all is well DB will transmit

```
echo 'ok';
```

My ajax success

```
success: function (data) {
  if (data == "ok") {
    document.write ("It's work!");
  };
}
```

But unfortunately it does not work.
Maybe it is necessary somehow break the data into two parts, script and other text.

Comment: Have you tried logging `data` to see what value it is getting?

Comment: when you say it doesn't work, what exactly does it mean?

Comment: Don't use `document.write`.

Comment: *"Maybe it is necessary somehow break the data into two parts, script and other text."* Yes, because `data` is going to contain both your script and the "ok" text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're sending out the response straight away to the server with `echo '<script>show_info("my_text")</script>';` as a response. because of this, `data` won't evaluate to 'ok'.

Instead, you should send back an array:

```
$ret = array(
    'script' => 'show_info("my_text")',
    'status' => 'ok'
);
echo json_encode($ret); // <--this should be done after all processing
```

Then in the ajax function you need to add the `dataType` parameter

```
$.ajax({
    //etc
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
        if(data.status == 'ok'){
            eval(data.script);
        }
    }
});
```